# Why does python install sha256 always fail?

Tags: python, sha256

System：win server 2008
python：3.5.3

[image: This is the error returned by the console installation]

Comment: read the error message?

Comment: Not sure what's unclear about "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."

Comment: Sha256 depends on the c++ library, but I have this c library on my computer.

Comment: @wim This is the error message

Answer (score 1):

It's because Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required, but is presumably not installed.

Get it with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.

You can find it at http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools.

Comment: I am sure my computer has Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed, it shows Visual C++ 2015 redistribute 14.0...

Comment: It seems the installation is sure that it isn't. It could be worth trying to reinstall it (using the link given).